# ASP.net user management and GoDaddy shared hosting

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, asp.net-membership

I'm trying to use the asp.net (3.5) built in user management framework but I'm not 100% sure how to do this on godaddy. Google didn't help much, anyone have experience with this?

Comment: What specifically is the issue?

Comment: Please pay attention to the suggest prompts when tagging your question.  Any tag with a number less than 10 after it's name is probably wrong. Avoid creating new tags.

Comment: I'm trying to use asp.net's built in user management functionality; where I can add, remove, add users to groups or roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the tables that the membership provider uses, look in `%WINDIR\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727`. That is where the SQL statements used by the wizard are located. Also, check out: 
http://www.asp.net/Learn/Security/tutorial-04-vb.aspx
for a more thorough explaination of how memberships tables are set up. You can do all the same work that the admin tool does, just not in a GUI format.

Answer (score 3):

You can roll your own or find one. You cannot run the Asp.net configuration tool directly against your GoDaddy account. (If you notice, it's just another asp.net website runing in another dev web server via Visual Studio).

You can use the System.Web.Security.Membership and Roles static classes in the Membership Provider to hook into it. This is very easy to do.  Membership.GetUsers(), etc.

You can also use the stored procs to manually add/remove users and roles.

-Nathan

Answer (score 2):

Go to your hosting control center
in menu Content on top, go to IIS Management, 
there will be list of web folder, 
on top of the list you can see asp.net runtime versions and (modify) link in brackets, click on it. There you'll see if you are using asp.net 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

I have also had this problem.  About a year ago.  So I am curious to know what the solution might be, if there *is* one!   I was told by Go Daddy, back then, that they had ASP.net admin stuff "locked down" pretty tight.  I went back and forth with their help people, who had to actually escalate it - because the general help team didnt understand what I was asking.  What I ultimately did was I canceled my hosting service (they did give me a refund for unused time!) and I went over to a different host.  Hope this helps and I will be listening carefully to responses as I am curious to see if they changed OR if someone has a workaround.